# Classes and a friend function between them

Tags: c++, class, friend

I am learning class and friend function. 
I want the function eat() from the class Farm to access the variable price from the class Bull and change the price value. So I need to implement a friend function. I have problem to use function as I do not understand how to use it.
I got thoses errors:

```
gcc friendFClass.cc -lstdc++ -o friendFClass 
friendFClass.cc: In member function 'void Farm::eat(Bull)':
friendFClass.cc:43: error: 'class Bull' has no member named 'eat'
friendFClass.cc: In function 'int main()':
friendFClass.cc:54: error: 'class Bull' has no member named 'eat'
```

for this program:

```
#include <iostream>

class Bull; // declaration not full of Bull

class Farm { // declaration full of Farm

    double sizeFarm;
    double massBull;


    public:
    void eat(Bull eatingBull); // Ok Bull was declared 
    void init(double size, double mass) {
        this -> sizeFarm = size;    
        this -> massBull = mass;
    }
    void print() {
        std::cout << "size of the Farm: " << sizeFarm << "\nmass of a bull: " << massBull << std::endl;
    }

};

class Bull {

    int eatBullThisMonth;
    int price;

    friend void Farm::eat(Bull eatingBull); // Ok Farm was full deblared

    public:
    void init(int price) {
        this -> price = price;
    }
    void print() {
        std::cout << "Number of bull for the month: " << eatBullThisMonth << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Total price : " << price << std::endl;
    }

};

void Farm::eat(Bull eatingBull) {
    int pPrice = 12 * eatingBull.price;
    eatingBull.eat(pPrice);
    eatingBull.print();
}

int main() {
    Farm delacroix;
    Bull marguerite;

    delacroix.init(1260, 123);
    marguerite.init(159);

    marguerite.eat(); 

    return 0;

}
```

I do not know where to define the friend function, inside or outside the class farm and how to define it.
Thank you.

Comment: `eatingBull.eat(pPrice);` <--- What are you trying to do here? Class `Bull` has no function `eat`.

Comment: I want with a function from Farm (eat()) to change the value of price.

Comment: you are calling for a `eat(int)` function which is clearly not defined.

Comment: Hmm, the error issued by the compiler `'eat' is not a member of Bull` is clear. BTW what output do you expect?

Comment: I fail to notice that. I am looking my code to correct it.

Comment: BTW: `friend void Farm::eat(Bull eatingBull);` is pointless as `Farm::eat` is public anyway.

Comment: I do not know how to use a function friend

Comment: @ripeisripe please [edit] your question and clarify what the program is supposed to do according to the comments.

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: The code seems to work now as I think it will be. Can you take a look at it @Jabberwocky please. Thank you all.

Comment: @ripeisripe  Don't answer your own question by editing it as it makes no more sense now. You can [answer]  your own question. Please read this: [tour]. An no, I don't take a look. If you have another question, ask another question.

Comment: I do not have other questions, thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring a function as `friend` in another class, means it can access its private members, not that it inherits the method. In this case it means that `Farm::eat` has access to `Bull` private members, but `Bull` doesn't inherit `Farm::eat`.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is ok now as it was a misuse of function and misuse of call of a function. Here is the right code.

```
#include <iostream>

class Bull; // declaration not full of Bull

class Farm { // declaration full of Farm

    double sizeFarm;
    double massBull;


    public:
    void eat(Bull eatingBull); // Ok Bull was declared 
    void init(double size, double mass) {
        this -> sizeFarm = size;    
        this -> massBull = mass;
    }
    void print() {
        std::cout << "size of the Farm: " << sizeFarm << "\nmass of a bull: " << massBull << std::endl;
    }

};

class Bull {

    int eatBullThisMonth;
    int price;

    friend void Farm::eat(Bull eatingBull); // Ok Farm was full deblared

    public:
    void init(int price) {
        this -> price = price;
    }
    void print() {
        std::cout << "Number of bull for the month: " << eatBullThisMonth << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Total price : " << price << std::endl;
    }

};

void Farm::eat(Bull eatingBull) {
    int pPrice = 12 * eatingBull.price;
    eatingBull.init(pPrice); 
    eatingBull.print();
}

int main() {
    Farm delacroix;
    Bull marguerite;

    delacroix.init(1260, 123);
    marguerite.init(159);

    delacroix.eat(marguerite); 

    return 0;

}
```